# hover on one element effects all elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to create four elements on the left side where the text is out of the view. with hover on one element only this should slide in, but all elements slides in.
I didn't have an idea at this point. Why do all elements slide in?

```
<div class="fixed-icons">
<div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--booking">
    <span>booking</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--voucher">
    <span>voucher</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--phone">
    <span>phone</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--eye">
    <span>eye</span>
</div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.fixed-icons {
position: fixed;
top:40%;
right:0;

.fixed-icons__item {
border: 1px solid white;
background-color: #004576;
color: white;
padding: 0.25rem;
margin: 0.25rem;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right:-50px;
transition: 1s;

&:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  margin-right:0;

}
}
}
```

`codepen` [demo](http://codepen.io/muex/pen/WRNRrY)

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

Animating the `margin` property caused some weird results - replaced it with `transform`.

```css
.fixed-icons {
  position: fixed;
  top:40%;
  right:0;

  .fixed-icons__item {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #004576;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    margin: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right:-50px;
    transition: 1s;

    &:hover {
      transition: 1s;
      transform: translateX(-49px);

    }
  }
}
```

```html
Here's the solution.


Animating the `margin` property caused some weird results - replaced it with `transform`.

<div class="fixed-icons">
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--booking">
        <span>booking</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--voucher">
        <span>voucher</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--phone">
        <span>phone</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--eye">
        <span>eye</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWJWGq)**

Answer (score 1):

try this, i have edited your css

```css
.fixed-icons {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
}
.fixed-icons .fixed-icons__item {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #004576;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -50px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.fixed-icons .fixed-icons__item:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(-49px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create a New Pen</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fixed-icons">
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--booking">
        <span>booking</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--voucher">
        <span>voucher</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--phone">
        <span>phone</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--eye">
        <span>eye</span>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just copied and pasted my solution, everything is exactly the same. I will flag it.

Comment: thats your way of understanding, i cant do anything for that'

Answer (score 0):

try this, i dint understand your question exactly but as i understood i have done this, try this may be this will help you out

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
   font-family: "entypo", sans-serif;
}

a { 
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px 50px;
   background:white;
}

#sticky-social {
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
}

#sticky-social a {
   background: #333;
   color: #fff;
   display: block;
   height: 35px;
   font: 16px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
   line-height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   width: 35px;
}

#sticky-social a:hover span {
   left: 100%;
}

#sticky-social a span {
   line-height: 35px;
   left: -120px;
   position: absolute;
   text-align:center;
   width:120px;
}

#sticky-social a[class*="facebook"],
#sticky-social a[class*="facebook"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="facebook"] span { background: #3b5998; }

#sticky-social a[class*="twitter"],
#sticky-social a[class*="twitter"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="twitter"] span { background: #00aced; }

#sticky-social a[class*="gplus"],
#sticky-social a[class*="gplus"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="gplus"] span { background: #dd4b39; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="linkedin"],
#sticky-social a[class*="linkedin"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="linkedin"] span { background: #007bb6; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="instagrem"],
#sticky-social a[class*="instagrem"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="instagrem"] span { background: #517fa4; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="stumbleupon"],
#sticky-social a[class*="stumbleupon"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="stumbleupon"] span { background: #eb4924; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="pinterest"],
#sticky-social a[class*="pinterest"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="pinterest"] span { background: #cc2127; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="flickr"],
#sticky-social a[class*="flickr"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="flickr"] span { background: #ff0084; } 

#sticky-social a[class*="tumblr"],
#sticky-social a[class*="tumblr"]:hover,
#sticky-social a[class*="tumblr"] span { background: #32506d; }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Social Sidebar</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
  <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>
  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
  <p>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
  <p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>
  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
  <p>Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.</p>
  <p>Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac</p>
 </div>
 <aside id="sticky-social">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-facebook" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-twitter" target="_blank"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-gplus" target="_blank"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-linkedin" target="_blank"><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-instagrem" taget="_blank"><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-stumbleupon" target="_blank"><span>StumbleUpon</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-pinterest" target="_blank"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-flickr" target="_blank"><span>Flickr</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="entypo-tumblr" target="_blank"><span>Tumblr</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

the direction of container causes this problem and you must set width length for the items. 
try this code:

```css
.fixed-icons {
  position: fixed;
  top:40%;
  right:0;
  .fixed-icons__item {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #004576;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    margin: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right:-50px;
    transition: 1s;
    width:80px;
    &:hover {
      transition: 1s;
      margin-right:0;

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="direction:rtl;">
      <div class="fixed-icons">
          <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--booking">
              <span>booking</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--voucher">
              <span>voucher</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--phone">
              <span>phone</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fixed-icons__item fixed-icons__item--eye">
              <span>eye</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```